# rsync: error starting client-server protocol

Tags: rsync

I have rsyncd running on both the systems . When I am trying to check the connection it giving me following error:

**From host2:**

```
user@host2#rsync username@host1::share
password: [password] 

@ERROR: auth failed on module share
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1524) [Receiver=3.0.7]
```

**On host1:**

I have following configuration

```
vim /etc/rsyncd.conf

max connections = 2
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
timeout = 300

[share]
comment = Public Share
path = /home/subhransu
read only = no
list = yes
uid = backuppc
gid = backuppc
auth users = backuppc
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

**On host1**

```
tail /var/log/rsync.log

2013/04/09 03:47:15 [29179] forward name lookup for cust-198-154-126-179.corexchange.com failed: No address associated with hostname
2013/04/09 03:47:15 [29179] connect from UNKNOWN (198.154.126.179)
2013/04/09 03:47:18 [29179] auth failed on module share from unknown (198.154.126.179): unauthorized user
```

Note: `rsyncd.secrets` has correct `user:passwd` , No firewall issue.

Comment: `auth users = backuppc` - is "username" in "From Host2:" equal to "backuppc"?

Comment: the name of your user is "username" or is this just an example? As far as I rememenber you don't need to use a username in the command line, as you have defined it in the module.

Comment: Also: Check the permissions on the secrets file - if running in "strict mode" (**default**), it must be readable only by the uid running the `rsyncd` daemon.

Comment: Thks for the help MattBiancoa and Hartmut.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the `uid` and `gid` parameters in the server config file are for privilege separation.

The `auth users` parameter in your config explicitly denies all other usernames than "`backuppc`".

So, you need "backuppc" in the rsyncd.secrets on "Host1", as well as on the command line on "Host2".

Try removing the `auth users` statement from `/etc/rsyncd.conf`, or double-check that you are indeed user `backuppc` on Host2 (not "user" or "username", as in the example "From host2:").

When troubleshooting, also try adding `strict modes = false` to your rsyncd config file.

Comment: Thnks! it helped

Comment: In the `rsync`command [manpage](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html), section `USING RSYNC-DAEMON FEATURES VIA A REMOTE-SHELL CONNECTION`, we can find that information (last paragraphs).

Answer (score 1):

0

I had the same issue in case of CentOS 7. I went through lot of articles ,forums but couldnt find out the solution. The problem was with SElinux. Disabling SElinux at the server end worked. Check SELinux status at the server end (from where you are pulling data using rysnc) Commands to check SELinux status and disable it

$getenforce

Enforcing ## this means SElinux is enabled

$setenforce 0

$getenforce

Permissive

Now try running rsync command at the client end ,it worked for me. All the best!

Comment: The better apporch to this isn't disabling SELinux but adding a context to allow rsync to access the path you want to share for example with `semanage fcontext -a -t rsync_data_t '/mnt/storage'` `restorecon -v '/mnt/storage'`

Answer (score 0):

Check also if rsyncd.conf has proper rights set:

```
chmod 640 /etc/rsyncd.cond
```

Comment: This is seemingly not related error, but is exactly the reason for error message like this. Except I prefer chmod 600 /etc/rsyncd.cond